# Adding Legend to Chloropleth map in GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas

I am trying to add a legend to my chrloropleth map in GeoPandas and there is a option to set : `legend = True`, but it comes up with the following error:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in plot_dataframe(s, column, cmap, color, linewidth, categorical, legend, ax, scheme, k, vmin, vmax, figsize, **color_kwds)
    284             else:
    285                 # TODO: show a colorbar
--> 286                 raise NotImplementedError
    287     plt.draw()
    288     return ax

NotImplementedError:
```

Which appears to be saying that the function hasn't been written.  The thing is I see examples of people using it on the internet so I was wondering if there was a common fix for this that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2):

`legend = True` is currently functional only for categorical plots.

There is a patch to enable this in chloropleth maps, see [Choropleth map from Geopandas GeoDataFame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755886/choropleth-map-from-geopandas-geodatafame).

Comment: should be working for categorical and continuous responses