# Adding `column` to geoDataFrame.plot gives TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a [geodataframe](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html) that I'm trying to plot.

With no args it happily plots this:

[image]

But when I try this `gp_aircon_df.geometry.plot(column="coolingHours", cmap='spring');` I get:

`TypeError: There is no Line2D property "column"`

The df is really simple:

```
    coolingHours  geometry
0   5377          POLYGON ((130.834539712 -12.45798405399995, 13...
1   5377          POLYGON ((130.8471142530001 -12.37754403699995...
.
.
```

Any idea what's going on?

(It's not [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755886/choropleth-map-from-geopandas-geodatafame))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the arguments to .geometry.plot() as a dictionary first. eg:

```
ch = dict(column="coolingHours", colormap = "spring")
gp_aircon_df.geometry.plot(**ch)
```

[image: Choropleth example image]